ER Diagram Chen Notation with Arrows
I am reading Ramakrishnan - Database Management Systems 3rd Edition, and they are using a version of Chen Notation to draw ER diagrams, with that said all the resources I have found do not use arrows and instead use ratios such as 1 to many or many to many. I am trying to understand what the arrows mean in this diagrams, alternatively sources which discuss this version of the Chen Notation would also be appreciated.Chen Diagram
I have tried searching for resources online and reading the text book, but have not found any concrete documentation regarding the specific details of this version of Chen Notation.

I think it's an arrow always from the "child" to the "parent" entity, which is a simplification on the full ERD notation (which in full has cardinality and optionality), as well as it is reminiscent of the generic use of arrows to indicate dependencies.

...which in full has cardinality and optionality, and on both sides...  The directionality is not even there in the conceptual-level models, these become directed graphs at a more concrete/implementative level.
